# selenium cucumber, how to count table rows

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a table with pagination, I would like to count all the rows of this table, this is what I did  :

```
   Then /^I should have (\d+) table rows$/ do |number_of_rows|
 actual_number = page.all('.table.table-striped tr').size
 actual_number.should == number_of_rows
end
```

BUT, I got this error :

```
undefined method `page' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0xb628dc20 browser=:chrome> (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your block is evaluated in the context of the instance of your web driver. The WebDriver does not have a page method but it does have methods for finding elements. How does this work for you?

```
Then /^I should have (\d+) table rows$/ do |number_of_rows|
  actual_number = $driver.find_elements({css:'.table.table-striped tr'}).size
  actual_number.should == number_of_rows
end
```

Comment: your code works, but it looks like size has one extra count,  here is what I got    Then I should have 8 table rows
features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:49
expected: 8
     got: 9 (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)

Comment: @Majid that does not sound like something I can help with since I have no idea what your source looks like. It seems very likely that this "extra" row is your header row so you might have to change your selector if you are only interested in the body

Comment: engineersmnky, thanks lot, yes, you are right, it was the header.